# Render 2 models on the same template using CBV

Tags: python, django

I am trying to **render** two **differents** models using a loop in my templates/dashboard/home.html using **Class Based View**.

Let's have a look on my code :

**views.py**

```
class DashboardListView(ListView):
model = Links
template_name = 'dashboard/home.html' 

class ContentListView(ListView):
model = Dashboard
template_name = 'dashboard/home.html'
```

First I would like to used **the same ListView** but was unable to do so.

My **home.html**

```
{% for dashboard in object_list %}  {{dashboard.content}}  {% endfor %}

{% for links in object_list %} {{links.content}} {% endfor %}
```

I would like to render those two models but **I can only render one** and the other object list will take the content for the preivous one.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can specify a different  Mae for the list of your objects using:

```
context_object_name =‘links_list’
```

Then you can add different elements to the context extending this method:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet 
     context[‘dashboard_list’]= Dashboard.objects.all()

    return context
```

Comment: Well it is not very clear yet. 
Let's suppose I want from my models **Links** and **Dashboard** two to be render in **home.html** : 

Following your answer I should do something like that : 


"class DashboardListView(ListView):
    model = Links
    template_name = 'dashboard/home.html'
    context_object_name ='links_list'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    
        context['dashboard_list']= Dashboard.objects.all()

        return context"

But it does make sense to me because there is still a model

Comment: @GaëtanGR exactly, just take care of using the right indentation to define the get_context_data. And then update your template with: {% for dashboard in dashboard_list %} and {% for links in links_list %}. The class based view get automatically the first model and then you aggregate the second one in the context. The context is a dict you pass to your template.